# Unable to find nib named error when trying to load nib from within a framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks

I've got a 'Main app' and a 'Helper app' (sandboxed, if that matters) that share a private framework including some resources, nib files, sound files etc.

The framework gets called and used by both apps without issues. However from within in the Framework code I have a `NSViewController` that loads a nib file which is included in its resource folder. This seems to work as long as its called by the 'Main app'. Doing the same with the Helper app (a login item) however does not work and fails with an `"Unable to find nib named"` error.

The actual 'Framework' is copied to the Main app's 'Frameworks' directory and I use a @rpath in the helper app to find the framework: `@executable_path/../../../../Frameworks`

This setup seems to work just fine however at runtime it seems the frameworks code tries to find the named Resource under the helper app's Resource folder and not under the Framework's resource folder. Is there a setting or some flag that I can set in xcode to make the framework's always look under the exact path where the framework's executable/library is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only solution is to copy the framework to the 'Helper' app as well. Resources otherwise do not get loaded if the framework was just a symbolic link to the actual framework placed inside the main app.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is making your Framework dynamic or shared like described here [Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)

Though it is a bit of a complex process, but a very nice feature.

What else can help you?
Perhaps editing the Library Search Paths or the Framework Search Paths under your Build Settings in Xcode. there you can specify additional search paths to look for.

Even though, I would not copy the Framework to the Main app's dir. I would leave it in one place on your disk, add them to your project (Main and helper) and add the specified search path.

By the way: How is your framework implemented? Is it a folder, is it compiled, or is it only code files?

Comment: Unfortunately Dynamic Libraries won't work given I need to share the resources between apps and the correct way of doing that is using a Framework. Moreover given my app's sandboxed and the framework is meant to be private I can't go the other route of placing the framework in a shared location. 

Having said that as explained below I managed to work around it by copying the framework to the helper app which then allows me to load the bundled resources correctly. A pain since I was trying to save on memory/space but oh well.

Comment: Ok, I kinda thought of an answer like that. Wasn't sure, how your implementation looked like. But now I know better. Reducing memory allocation is only possible with dynamic libraries....